# how to convert different levels in one row

Tags: r, tidyverse, spread

I have a set of data like below:

```
BETA_LACT   R   I   S
-   23  25  91
-   30  0   109
-   0   0   136
+   73  0   0
+   14  0   59
+   0   0   49
```

I want to convert the data to the format below:

```
R_- I_- S_- R_+ I_+ S_+
23  25  91  73  0   0
30  0   109 14  0   59
0   0   136 0   0   49
```

I tried spread() but failed, could anybody help me?

Comment: "I tried spread() but failed, could anybody help me?" Can you include what you tried and what the error message is?

Comment: Try gathering the letter columnar first, then unite, then spread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem using `spread` and `gather` is that there is nothing your sample data to suggest which rows should be collapsed. As a *human*, I can observe that you wish to combine rows 1 and 4, 2 and 5, etc. However, there are no other columns or "keys" persay in your dataset to indicate this.

One solution would be to add an index column as I show in the second example below using `group_by` and `mutate`. The following `reprex` (reproducible example) shows both a non-working example analogous to your case and a working example.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

example_data <- data.frame(
  categ = rep(1:3, 3),
  x = 1:9,
  y = 11:19,
  z = 21:29
)

# won't work
example_data %>%
  gather(var, value, -categ) %>%
  unite(new_col_name, var, categ) %>%
  spread(new_col_name, value)
#> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (10, 13, 16), (11, 14, 17), (12, 15, 18), (19, 22, 25), (20, 23, 26), (21, 24, 27)

# will work
example_data %>%
  group_by(categ) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(var, value, -categ, -id) %>%
  unite(new_col_name, var, categ) %>%
  spread(new_col_name, value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>      id   x_1   x_2   x_3   y_1   y_2   y_3   z_1   z_2   z_3
#> * <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     2     3    11    12    13    21    22    23
#> 2     2     4     5     6    14    15    16    24    25    26
#> 3     3     7     8     9    17    18    19    27    28    29
```

*(As a sidenote, please check out the `reprex` package! This helps you make a "reproducible example" and ask better questions which will facilitate better community support. Notice how easy it is to copy the above code and run it locally.)*